# Stripe embedded form not appearing

Tags: stripe-payments

I have the below code.  If I throw it onto one page, the button shows up and I can see it through developer tools.  On another page, the button doesn't show up and dev tools shows the script tag missing in the form.  What could be causing this?

```
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                    data-key="sss"
                    data-amount="999"
                    data-name="sss"
                    data-description="Widget"
                    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                    data-locale="auto">
            </script>
        </form>
```

Comment: Have you fixed it? I'm searching for a solution but not lucky so far.